# How to combine multiple WFS into one?

Tags: wfs

Let's say I have two WFS layers from different sources. Both layers have the same data structure and application schema.

Is there an open source software package like Geoserver that I can use to "merge" them into one WFS layer which other services can then consume?

I've looked at cascading WFS but it doesn't seem to be what I need.

Comment: Did you try setting up both WFS as Vector data sources (GeoServer), creating layers for them and then grouping the layers, not sure if it''l work, but probably worth a try.

Comment: @nmtoken Not yet. Isn't layer grouping just for WMS?

Comment: Layers in general is a WMS thing, strictly WFS don't have any layers, just FeatureTypes, but in GeoServer and other software the configuration/gui just deals with _layers_.  So it was just a thought that you might be able to approach your problem this way. However I did just try with a MapServer WMS/WFS service that has grouped WMS layers and see the WFS doesn't expose the grouped layer as a collective FeatureType :(

Comment: Just thinking about this a bit more, I can see a potential problem with merging on the fly, which would be the potential clash of gml:ids.  The id's must be unique in a service response, but there would be no way of ensuring that two services didn't have the same ids.  Compare http://min4eu.geologie.ac.at/m4eu/services?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=2.0.0&typename=ge:MappedFeature& with http://194.66.252.155/m4eu/services?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=2.0.0&typename=ge:MappedFeature& for example.

Comment: @nmtoken Thanks for the info! I'm actually thinking of using a mediator but I don't know how to implement it. All I see are papers.